# SQL Query To See if Sums Dont Add Up

Tags: sql, qsqlquery

I have the two tables below is in a database

Is there a SQL query that can get all the invoicesamounts from the invoice detail table and see if the sum of the detailamount based on the invoicenum dont add up to the total invoiceamount to the corresponding invoice number in the invoice table?

**Invoice Table**

```
invoicenum | invoicedate | invoiceamount
-----------+-------------+--------------
00551198 | 1/1/2014 | $150.5
00551199 | 1/2/2014 | $10
```

**invoiceDetail Table**

```
invoicenum | trackingno | detailamount
-----------+--------------------+-------------
00551198 | 1Z2F12346861507266 | $50
00551198 | 1Z2F12346861507267 | $80
00551198 | 1Z2F12346861507268 | $20.5
00551199 | 1Z2F12346861503423 | $10.5
```

Answer (score 1):

An aggregation and `join` should do the trick:

```
select i.*, id.sumdetail
from invoices i left join
     (select id.invoicenum, sum(detailamount) as sumdetail
      from invoicedetail id
      group by id.invoicenum
     ) id
     on i.invoicenum = id.invoicenum
where id.sumdetail <> i.invoicenum or id.sumdetail is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query

```
select *, case when t1.s=i.invoiceamount then 'equal' else 'not equal' end from invoice i 
left join
(select sum(detailamount) as s, invoicenum from invoicedetail group by invoicenum) as t1
on t1.invoicenum = i.invoicenum
```